# Process Email as an attachment of another email in logic apps

Tags: azure, email, azure-logic-apps

I need to process in an azure logic app an email that comes as an attachment of another email. Is there a painless/direct way of doing this or the best approach would be to call a function app with the email attachment, i.e. the email I am interested in and there process this email?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to send the contents of the email to a storage account and then get the same content using the `Get blob content` connector and then using the same blob content as an attachment to the mail that we are sending.

Here is my logic app
[image]

[image]

If you use the same email account for both the connectors then it will fall into infinite loop and triggers mails.

For more information on how to add pictures as attachments through logic apps, you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/379700/how-to-embed-image-in-logic-apps-send-email-v2.html).